# Cant access object values in vueX in actions

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-cli

I´m writing a method in VueX store to upload a object converted to a json to Firebase.
In vuex store under action I have created a method called scheduleTickets(purchase) but in the methods I cant access the value in the purchase object. 
But If I commit to a mutations function and send the object to it I can access them but not from actions.
Am I doing something wrong here?

```
async scheduleTickets(purchase){
      let documents = JSON.stringify(purchase)
      for(let document of documents){
        console.log(document)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using plain JavaScript or any kind of TypeScript modules?

Comment: I´m just using Vue Cli

Comment: why are you `JSON.stringify`ing you data ? do you want to iterate over the chars of a json-string ?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      state.count++
    }
  },
  actions: {
    increment (context) {
      context.commit('increment')
    }
  }
})
```

You should have at least 2 arguments: `context` and second - `payload`. Override your method to this:

```
scheduleTickets(context, purchase){
      let documents = JSON.stringify(purchase)
      for(let document of documents){
        console.log(document)
      }
    }
```

And you can dispatch it like this:

```
// dispatch with a payload
store.dispatch('scheduleTickets', purchase)
```